# Error during razercfg install at 18.04

Tags: compiling, 18.04

During the installation of razercfg (https://github.com/mbuesch/razer) I recive a fallowing error. Internet didn't help. What can I do?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/XYZ/Downloads/razer-master/ui/setup.py", line 3, in 
from distutils.core import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.core'
ui/CMakeFiles/pyrazer.dir/build.make:61: recipe for target 'ui/build/stamp' failed
make[2]: *** [ui/build/stamp] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:195: recipe for target 'ui/CMakeFiles/pyrazer.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ui/CMakeFiles/pyrazer.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Installation of python3-distutils did resolve the issue.